# How to upgrade to ice-cream sandwish

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 2.3-gingerbread, updates

Can i upgrade my gingerbread android (v 2.3.6) to icecream sandwish android (v 4.0)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the device if you want the official install but with a lot of devices you will be able to install a custom ROM running ICS.

To check for the official upgrade go to settings -> about phone (or something similar) -> phone update/update software (or something similar).

For a custom ROM have a look on XDA developers, I would give more information if I knew which device you were speaking of.

Comment: well thanks but, could you show me or email me the way to install a custom  ROM running ICS please?

Comment: What device are you using?

Comment: Hisense U1+  but it got only 140 mb system storage and only 8 gb on sd card

Comment: Listen,how can i contact u ?
do u have Twitter or Facebook?

Comment: I assume the phone isn't rooted?

Comment: Nope,its not but i should so i can replace a custom ROm running ICS cuz i dont want to install the whole software.

Comment: This was the best I could find on rooting it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SIUsijYhz6s

Comment: Well,thanks alot but could u please leave me an adress i could contact u with ,just in case??